# Remove overlay view on touch

Tags: iphone, uiview, objective-c++

I defined a UIview as an overlay view:

```
self.disableViewOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,44.0f,320.0f,416.0f)];
self.disableViewOverlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
```

Now I would like to disable the overlay view if a user taps on it...

```
[disableViewOverlay removeFromSuperview];
```

How do I find out if the user taps on this overlay view? Is there a "tapped" method just like a button has an IBAction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. overriding `hitTest` in your `UIView`;
2. overriding `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` for greater control.

Both approaches require that you subclass your `UIView` (the one you want to detect the tap  on).

Have a look at [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) or [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) respectively.

If you do not want to subclass your `UIView`, another option is attaching it to a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
 gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnView)];
 [self.disableViewOverlay addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

you would then disable the overlay in the `handleTapOnView` function.
Gesture recognizers are available only from iOS 3.2 on.

Check this: [UITapGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer)